# Python SQL UPDATE Time

Tags: python, sql, datetime, time, sql-update

I have to make day_log equal to time, which is now. Type of day_log is VARCHAR(30) What am I doing wrong?

```
from _datetime import datetime
time=datetime.now()
mytime=str(time.time())
cursor.execute("""UPDATE birthday SET day_log = %s WHERE day_log = '4'""" %(mytime))
```

Comment: why is your day a varchar? Use a timestamp!